# Выводится мусор при поиске элементов в рандомной матрице

Tags: c, массивы, матрицы

Почему, когда я ищу элементы, которые делятся на сумму индексов и не делятся на 5, мне выводится какой-то мусор? Такой алгоритм работает с матрицей, если бы я вводил ее с консоли, а вот с рандомной нет. Благодарю за объяснение заранее!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "color.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

main()
{
    time_t t;
    srand(time(&t));
    int c[10][10], b[10], n, i, j;

    do
        n = rand() % 10;
    while (n < 2 || n > 5);
    printf("n=%i\n", n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++, puts(""))
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf("%4i", c[i][j] = rand() % 7 - 1);
            puts("");
        }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++, puts(""))
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (c[i][j] < 0)
                SetColor(12);
            else if (c[i][j] == 0)
                SetColor(9);
            else
                SetColor(15);
            printf("%4i", c[i][j]);
        }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++, puts(""))
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (((i + j) != 0) && ((c[i][j] % (i + j)) == 0) && (c[i][j] % 5 != 0))
            {
                b[j] = c[i][j];
            }
        }
    printf("\nelementi kotorie deleatsea na summu  indexov i ne deletsea na 5:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%4i", b[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данной задаче использование вспомогательного массива излишне.

Предлагаю вот эту часть кода

```
if (((i + j) != 0) && ((c[i][j] % (i + j)) == 0) && (c[i][j] % 5 != 0))
{
    b[j] = c[i][j];
}
```

заменить на

```
if (((i + j) != 0) && ((c[i][j] % (i + j)) == 0) && (c[i][j] % 5 != 0))
{
    printf("%4i", c[i][j]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Мусор выводится по той причине, что у Вас не инициализирован массив `b`. И потому, что количество присвоенных значений у массива `b` меньше, чем текущее `n`. Более того, Вы заполняете массив `b` не подряд (если хотите заполнять подряд, то для массива `b` стоило бы добавить свой индекс (счетчик)).

Возможный вариант решения проблемы: задаете еще одну переменную (инициализируете нулем, раз мы хотим ее использовать как индекс для `b`)

```
int count=0;
...
// внутри циклов пользетесь для массива b новым индексом и сразу увеличиваете
  b[count++] = c[i][j];
...
// выводите в цикле до count
for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    printf("%4i\n", b[i]);
}
```