# почему в строке появляются лишние символы?

Tags: c, функции, split

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void split(char s[], char sep, char ans[5][10]) {
    int word = 0;
    int letter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++) {
        if (s[i] == sep) {
            letter = 0;
            word++;
        }
        else ans[word][letter++] = s[i];
    }
}
int main() {
    char a[5][10];
    char* strin = "no ababa ppp!";
    split(strin, ' ', a);
    printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n", a[0], a[1], a[2]);
}
```

вывод:

```
no╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠ababa╠╠╠╠╠ppp!╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠xЭ▐qЎ
ababa╠╠╠╠╠ppp!╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠xЭ▐qЎ
ppp!╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠xЭ▐qЎ
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [выводится мусор при поиске элементов в рандомной матрицу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1086592/%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d1%83%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%83)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Локальные переменные, живущие на стеке (у вас это `char a[5][10];`) не инициализируются нулями по умолчанию и изначально содержат мусор.
То есть, null-terminator нужно дописывать руками.

Например, так:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++) {
        if (s[i] == sep) {
            ans[word][letter] = 0; // <-- терминатор
            letter = 0;
            word++;
        }
        else ans[word][letter++] = s[i];
    }
    ans[word][letter] = 0; // <-- терминатор
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное